# Alternative for this query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find out who the friends of 'x' are, and using that array of data to query another table.

What I have so far is

```
<?
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/global/scripts/***.php');
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hotm**e_rates WHERE (SELECT * FROM hot**e_friends WHERE f1='$user' OR f2='$user') ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
if($row['f1']==$user) {
echo $row['f2'];
}else{
echo $row['f1'];
}
?>
```

That doesnt work. :(
error is that the return val is a bool.

Any ideas on how to fix this or use an alternative?

thanks! :D

Comment: I think your tablename-censoring is kind of pointless. Kind of obvious that that the tables are called `hotmate_*`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `hotmule_*`

Comment: It seems you didn't complete the condition after `where`.

Comment: @nachito, It has only 2 *... MUL is 3 letters.

Comment: your schema seems bad. Try normalising the data. `f1 = '$user' or f2 = '$user'` smells to me (And is also probably open to sql injection)

Comment: neither hotmate or hotmule, hotmule was closer though ;D Try again!

Comment: I've got that suggestion before, I'm not really sure how to do that, the f1/f2 is a table of friends, where f1 is the person who is adding someone, and f2 is the person to accept the request, so an OR is all I can do to find links :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it like Jeff suggests - if the user has more than 1 friendship then it will fail since the subquery will return more than one row. I'm assuming that there is a field 'username' in the hotm**e_rates table, that we can use to join to. I've also made the assumption that you want to get all the _rates that are associated with the friends of $user:

```
SELECT
    r.*,
    f.f1,
    f.f2
FROM
    hotm**e_rates   r,
    hotm**e_friends f
WHERE
    (f.f1 = '$user'
AND r.username = f.f2)
OR  (f.f2 = '$user'
AND r.username = f.f1)
```

I'm not entirely sure if the above will work since it's joining dynamically on different fields... that might be problematic and I haven't tested it, if it doesn't work then you should be able to do it with a union, joining on the f1 and f2 separately and unioning the result sets together:

```
(   SELECT
        r.*,
        f.f1,
        f.f2
    FROM
        hotm**e_rates   r,
        hotm**e_friends f
    WHERE
        f.f1 = '$user'
    AND r.username = f.f2
) UNION (
   SELECT
        r.*,
        f.f1,
        f.f2
    FROM
        hotm**e_rates   r,
        hotm**e_friends f
    WHERE
        f.f2 = '$user'
    AND r.username = f.f1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The value returned is bool because an error occurred in your MYSQL query. 
You have to set something like `WHERE [main_query_table] = (SELECT [table_field] FROM hot**e_friends WHERE f1='$user' OR f2='$user')`.

References:

- [Mysql subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html)

Comment: Oh! I thought there was something to do with a union which I have no idea about. I didn't realize you had to do that! Thank you! :)